# AttributeError: 'Animal' object has no attribute 'get_name'

Tags: python, class

Can anyone help me solve this error, I'm stumped on this. I'm trying to create an animal class and create a name, mood and animal type for each animal. I am getting this error no matter how I change animalGenerator.py Thanks for the help!

Animal.py

```
import random
class Animal:
    __animal_type = ""
    __name = ""
    __mood = ""
    
    def __init__(self, animal_type, name):
        self.__animal_type = animal_type
        self.__name = name

        num = random.randint(1,3)
        if (num == 1):
            self.__mood = "happy"
        elif (num == 2):
            self.__mood = "hungry"
        elif (num == 3):
            self.__mood = "sleepy"

def get_animal_type(self):
    return self.__animal_type

def get_name(self):
    return self.__name

def check_mood(self):
    return self.__mood
```

animalGenerator.py

```
import Animal


print('Welcome to the animal generator!')
print('This program creates Animal objects.')

animals = []

while True:
    animal_type = input("What type of animal would you like to create?")
  
    name = input("What is the animal's name?")
  
    new_animal = Animal.Animal(animal_type, name)
    animals.append(new_animal)
  
    again = input("\nWould you like to add more animals (y/n)? ")
    if(again != 'y'):
        break
  
print("\nAnimal List")

for l in animals:
    print(l.get_name(), 'the', l.get_animal_type(), 'is', l.check_mood())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your indentation in Animal.py